# Create Azure Resource Group Template with parametrized connections

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-connect

I'm trying to create a **template** of an **Azure resource group** in order to have a *dev* resource group and a *test* resource group. Logic Apps, Service bus, etc works fine, but connections are not setting ok because I don't know how to set, for example of an SQL connection or ServiceBus connection, its server address via parameter, sql user, password... It only appears the connection name when I get the template of my test resource group in my parameters json file.

How can I do it?

Is this way correct?

`"properties": {
                "displayName": "OperationalSqlDev",
              "customParameterValues": {
                "authType": "windows",
                "database": "[parameters('sqlDatabase')]",
                "password": "[parameters('sqlPassword')]",
                "server": "[parameters('sqlServer')]",
                "username": "[parameters('sqlUser')]"
              },`

Comment: i dont understand the question. can you rephrase or provide an example?

Comment: I have generated a template of a resource group which has in it several logic apps and several connections to service bus and sql server. But, when deploying the template to another resource group, the only value I can change in the parameters file is the name of the connection, not the service bus endpoint, sql server name, sql user, sql password... I want to have them in parameters file also.

Comment: okay, what prevents you from doing so?

Comment: How do I give parameters value to them? (you can check the way I've made it)

Answer (score 1):

if your question is how to use parameters and parameters file you can take a look at an examples in the [examples repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-simple-linux).

In general you define parameters in parameters section of the template and then you assign values using parameters file or inline with powershell\cli\what_have_you